# How does kotest and maven parallelism work?

Tags: kotlin, maven, kotest

Does kotest run tests in parallel if maven is running on multiple threads like mvn -T 3?
If maven is on -T 1, then how does parallelism work in kotest?

Comment: It should, as Kotest should create a thread pool with the available threads. In your case 3, so the max achievable parallelism would be 3. I have no clue on how that works with maven, unfortunately. I think you'll have to run some experiments